# Adult Swim anime movie had people in robots fighting kaiju-like creatures

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched a show 6-8 years ago about people that got into robots to fight kaiju-like creatures. It was kind of like *Pacific Rim*. The main character was a guy who was school. A girl that tried to control one of the robots had gotten severely hurt when fighting a kaiju creature.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is a little tropey and would significantly benefit from you going through the checklists here to identify some unique features; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 10):

This sounds a lot like [Neon Genesis Evangelion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion). It aired on Adult Swim in 2005 and has popped up on their schedules repeatedly since then.

The main character, Shinji is a <s>mopey little sod</s> schoolboy who's forced to pilot a gigantic mecha and fight kaiju-like "angels". One of the other protagonists is a young girl called Rei. She gets seriously injured about once every other episode.

Answer (score 1):

It might be [Dual! Parallel Trouble Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual!_Parallel_Trouble_Adventure), but this plot is so general that it could be a lot of things, like [Fafner in the Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fafner_in_the_Azure) or [RahXephon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RahXephon) maybe.

In Dual! Parallel Trouble Adventure our main character sees something that no-one else sees, giant robots fighting other kaiju-like things. He meet girls (which is interesting with his story) later he move to parallel universe where he takes over a mecha because the girl who pilot him was injured

Fafner is almost exactly kids-fight-with-help-of-mecha-vs-alien-monsters.

RahXephon again sees a boy see some monster attack city, he meets a girl who leads him to strange undergrounds with a big robot which he use to fight monsters

Comment: Can you explain how the shows in your answer match the description given?

Comment: first show our main character see something what no one else see giant robots fighting other kaiju a like things he meet girls which is interesting with hes story later he move to parallel universe where he take mecha because Girl who pilot him was injured ...Fafner is almost exactly kids fight with help of mecha alien monsters and RahXephon again boy see some monster attack city he meets a girl who leads him to strange undergrounds with a big robot which he use to fight monsters

Answer (score -1):

Adult Swim also showed *Big O*. The girl was an android named Dorothy. The main character was officiakly a "Negotiator", but was more of a hardcore detective and could handle himself in a fight, even when not in Big O. One unusual element was that the pilot of the mech would be judged by the mech.
Each episode had the town attacked by some form of kaiju.

Comment: Your description doesn't seem to match the question asked